# The current song duplicates after shuffling. I need guidance in preventing duplicates from happening

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, methods

I'm trying to develop a simple music application. I am struggling with the shuffle method as the current song that is playing is getting duplicated as I press the shuffle button. Is there any way I can prevent it from duplicating? I do not plan on doing the easier ways of using array lists and the `Collections.shuffle` method.

```
 private void prepareSongs()
{
    Song theWayYouLookTonight = new Song("S1001", "The Way You Look Tonight","Michael Buble","a5b8972e764025020625bbf9c1c2bbb06e394a60?cid=null",4.39,"michael_buble_collection");
    Song billieJean = new Song("S1002","Billie Jean","Michael Jackson","4eb779428d40d579f14d12a9daf98fc66c7d0be4?cid=null",5.45,"billie_jean");
    Song outinSpace = new Song("S1003","Out in Space","Whiz Khalifa","3d691281fae7d4ba8c5907887d2a31ce064891b3?cid=null",2.83,"wiz_khalifa");

    //This is my songs array
    songs[0] = theWayYouLookTonight;
    songs[1] = billieJean; 
    songs[2] = outinSpace;
}

//Shuffle method
 public Song getShuffleSong(String currentSongId)
{
    Song song = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++)
    {
        if(songs[i].getId().equals(currentSongId))
        {
            //This part of the code is bugging me 
            song = songs[(int)(Math.random() * 3)]; 
            break;
        }
    }
    return song;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what the expected result is?

Comment: Q: Do you mean *always* duplicates ... or "occasionally duplicates"?  The only way to prevent "occasionally duplicates" is to save a reference to the previous track ... and then reshuffle if the new track == the previous one.  Because "random" means precisely that ;)

Comment: Expected result is for example I'm playing the song Billie Jean, if I press the shuffle button I wouldn't want Billie Jean to play again. I need a random song which is either The Way You Look Tonight or Out in Space to be played instead. Thank you.

Comment: A: Occasionally duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to continuously generate random indexes until the song at the index is not the current song.

```
public Song getShuffleSong(String currentSongId) {
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * songs.length);
    while (songs[rand].getId().equals(currentSongId)) {
        rand = (int) (Math.random() * songs.length);
    }
    return songs[rand];
}
```

Alternatively, you could store all of the indexes still available in a `List` that is updated regularly, which would only require obtaining one random index from that list.